# Spring framework import failed

Tags: spring, gradle

I am starting on Spring and learning its foundations. I created a project in intellij

It was giving an error stating that web cannot be imported.

[image]

so i guessed it must have been . my gradle build file which does not have web

I tried to import in manually via the build.gradle file as below but it throws me an error saying it cannot be found.

WHat am i doing wrong and how can i resolve this?

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'io.codementor.gtommee'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

any help?

Comment: An error as below? Where is the error? Post code and errors as text, not as images. Don't use snapshot releases to learn. Use the final release. And yes, to use Spring MVC, you need the web starter. Go back to start.spring.io, and generate a new project with a release version, and the appropriate dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in your build.gradle file.

To get started, have a look at https://start.spring.io/